# Error 10054 when publish to Azure from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, deployment, azure-devops

I have been using a publish profile from Visual Studio to publish my web app for about a year. Over the past week or two the process gets stuck and does a few retries until it fails. The error I am getting is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4295,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.
>   2>Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.

Points to note:

- Nothing has changed on my network
- The publish profile is version controlled and is the same
- The publish **doesn't** fail from the beginning. It publishes for a while.
- Seems to fail if the file is bigger than ~10 or 15 MB
- Others who have this issue, seems to be their ISP or their network but
  it seems theirs fails from the beginning.
- Tried it with two different publish profiles on two different subscription accounts resulting the same problem

Anyone has seen this? any ideas?

Comment: "This issue occurs because the TCP/IP driver does not close an incomplete TCP connection. Instead, the TCP/IP driver sends a notification that the TCP/IP driver is ready to receive data when the incomplete TCP connection is created. Therefore, the application receives an instance of the 10054 error that indicates that a connection is reset when the application receives data from the connection."

Comment: Also: have Azure security settings changed?

Comment: @rickvdbosch, thanks for the reply. No, I haven't changed anything. Remind you that I even tried to do this with couple of publish profiles on two different subscription accounts and still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the issue is resolved. I had checked every bit, including calling my ISP, and didn't have any luck. Thanks to @rickvdbosch for mentioning the TCP/IP relevance to this problem that juggled my memory.

A few weeks ago, I upgraded the firmware on my router (as I am using DDWRT). I believe that was the culprit. I did upgrade to the latest DDWRT firmware and I see the issue is gone. It is deploying as before all the drama started.

So if another poor soul comes across this error, wish you luck but be aware of this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

And thank you - StackedUp.. What you did with the firmware upgrade (i don;t have access to do that) made me think to try using my phone's internet instead (change the "router" providing internet). And that worked for me. Thanks all.